# Wordpress white screen or memory limit on https

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have very strange situation. When I open my site normally using http, everything working very good but when I use ssl and open using https I see fatal error about memory limit alternating with white screen. Do you have any idea about the problem and it's solution ?

URL this site:
http://careercon.pl
https://careercon.pl

Answer (score 0):

**Try this solution for your error -**

**Increase PHP memory limit in WordPress**

There are a few ways to do this, and you may or may not be limited by your host, in which case, if the following fixes don’t work, you need to talk to them.

**First Option is Via wp-config.php**

```html
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

**Second Option is Via PHP.ini**

```html
memory_limit = 128M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
```

**Third option is Via .htaccess**

> If you don’t have access to your php.ini file, sometimes you can use
>   your .htaccess file to set the memory limit:

```html
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error still occurs and what's more when I add line in .htaccess I get error 500

Comment: I get this error on https: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 85 bytes) in /users/bamt2/home/www/wp-includes/meta.php on line 843

Comment: Please follow this link - https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/fix-wordpress-memory-exhausted-error-increase-php-memory/comment-page-1/